# ValueError: unknown url type: ' ' (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, valueerror

I am going to download pictures from a clothing website for academic research, I use the code below
`

```
from ast import keyword
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import os
import wget 

import random
import time

delay_choices = range(5,15)
delay = random.choice(delay_choices) 

import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
 
keyword = "jeans"
 
user_agent = UserAgent()
response = requests.get(url="https://www2.hm.com/en_asia3/ladies/shop-by-product/jeans.html", headers={ 'user-agent': user_agent.random })

driver = webdriver.Chrome("~~~~") 
driver.get("https://www2.hm.com/en_asia3/ladies/shop-by-product/jeans.html")
time.sleep(4)


cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
cookie.click()
time.sleep(2)

for i in range(6):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6900);")
    time.sleep(delay)
    loadmore = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button")
    loadmore.click()

imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-image')

path = os.path.join("H&M" + keyword)
os.mkdir(path)

count = 0
for img in imgs:
    save_as = os.path.join(path, keyword + str(count) + '.jpg')
    #print(img.get_attribute("src"))
    wget.download(img.get_attribute("src"), save_as)
    count += 1

time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

`

and I got this issue:
[image]
in this line: ***wget.download(img.get_attribute('src'), save_as)***

but I also use the "src" to download other website and didn't wrong.

I would wonder if anyone know what happen.

Thanks a lot.

I have searched and couldn't solve this problem, and I hope someone can give me some advice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTlBH.jpg)

Comment: At what line do you get the error. Please write the value of the parameters save_as and img.

Comment: What returns this line if you uncomment it: `print(img.get_attribute("src"))`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TalAngel in this line: wget.download(img.get_attribute('src'), save_as) thank you.

Comment: @EugenyOkulik Still the same .  Thanks!

Comment: Add the line `print('Image src is', img.get_attribute("src"))` somewhere before the line that returns error, run the code, copy the result and paste it here.

Comment: @EugenyOkulik still got the same problem.

Comment: This line I asked you to add doesn't fix anything. It just prints out the URL of the image. So, if we know the URL we'll probably find the solution how to fix this. So, add the line to the code, copy the result and paste it here

Comment: @EugenyOkulik I have added the results above! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are trying to download using `wget` has lots of specific symbols and this can cause problems for the `wget`. This is an example of the URL you are attempting to download from: [https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/2b/bf/2bbf11a29fde773adcdOK],res[y],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]](https://lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source%5B/2b/bf/2bbf11a29fde773adcdOK%5D,res%5By%5D,hmver%5B1%5D&call=url%5Bfile:/product/main%5D)
Try to change the command a bit:
Instead of this:

```
wget.download(img.get_attribute("src"), save_as)
```

try this:

```
wget.download(f'"{img.get_attribute("src")}"', save_as)
```